# How to get distinct values from a column with all its corresponding values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

> table_categories (id INT(11), cname VARCHAR(25),survey_id INT(11))

I want to retrieve the values for the column cname without duplication, that is distinct values but with all the values in the other column.

```
id  cname     survey_id
--  --------  ---------
 1  Trader     2
 2  Beginner   2
25  Human      1
26  Human      2
```

From the above example I want to retrieve distinct cnames with all the values of the survey_id.
I don't want to use any programming language. Is there any way by using a single query. Please give me a solution in MySQL.

Comment: Could you show your expected results?

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT cname, GROUP_CONCAT(survey_id) as survey_ids
FROM categories 
GROUP BY cname
```